# Storing images for LCD

Tags: tft

For TFT LCD, if we want to store images for displaying on screen..can we use flash IC for eg: [SST25VF020](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/S71417_03.pdf)_2Mbit serial(SPI) flash.

Please someone guide since I am newbie to TFT LCD interface. Thanks.

Comment: The question is too vague. It will likely get down-voted, and may get closed before you have a good answer. The simple answer is YES, *any* kind of storage, including a serial Flash memory should work.  However, to answer whether that specific part will work we need to know the other parts in the system, e.g. LCD, controller, microcontroller, etc. Please read the [help] to learn how to ask good questions that get good answers.

Comment: It's possible considering the string of bizarre and unanswerable questions on this topic that you don't have the experience level to tackle this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any form of storage to recall your images. But define an 'image'. Yes; the end result is probably very clear. But what format do you want to store them in? What size? How many? How fast do they need to be recalled?

From a hardware design, the storage device is probably very important.
But from a systems design probably very irrelevant; you can also use MCU's internal FLASH (if you got any spare), EEPROMs or SD cards to store them. But defining what data you put on the storage as an "graphic image" is more important.

For example: a 480x272x16-bit LCD needs 255kB bytes worth of raw pixel data. This is practically the same size as a BMP file. In 2Mbit, you can store 1 color bitmap. Alternatively you could store the same image in a PNG or JPEG format (much smaller), and use a decoder to get the pixel data back. However this requires extra code, CPU time and RAM.

That decision depends completely on the application.